# SharePoint Online - @font-face encountered Unknown Error

Tags: sharepoint-online

On SharePoint online when we browse the root site collection home page or any page we get the below two error in IE11 browser
[image]

Page is not having any customization and it occurred in even outside of Corporate Network in IE

Could anybody let me know if any solution for this issue. I want to avoid any error in console.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3111 is usually caused by an issue with the font's binary source. One of the popular online TTF to EOT converters for example produces EOT files with a NAME table that doesn't comply to the Microsoft standards, which results in EOT fonts that never load in IE and produce the CSS3111 error. So, when you experience a CSS3111, it is always good to try using a different TTF to EOT converter or font face generator.

You can check the similar post:
[IE9 - CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559592/ie9-css3111-font-face-encountered-unknown-error)

Comment: This is Microsoft Online SharePoint root site home page. we have not developed anything so cant do any changes. if you think this issue related to any browser settings so i can do the changes